# how to execute a function after another one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to execute `b()` **after** `a()` is executed.

i.e. - all titles should be `3` except the first one - it should be `5`.

Why nested `b()` inside `a()` doesn't work?

In reality a() is a much larger function and `a();b();` doesn't work

```js
function a(){
$('.title').text('3');
}

function b(){
$('.title').eq(0).text('5');
}

$('button').on('click', function(){
  a(b());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='title'>title</div>
<div class='title'>title</div>
<div class='title'>title</div>
<div class='title'>title</div>

<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: `a(); b();` - means "execute `a` first, then execute `b"`. `a(b())` means execute "`b` and pass the result to `a`" which also involves calling it but naturally that can only be done when the data is available..

Comment: You need to explain why `a(); b();` doesn't work. The size of the functions shouldn't matter.

Comment: Explain why `a(); b();` does not work, because in the example here it definitely does.  It is the perfect example of *"how to execute a function after another one"*

Comment: @Barmar, because `b()` is executed before `a()` is finshed, I suppose, so the final result is from `a()`

Comment: So there is something in `a()` that is asynchronous?

Comment: @Archer, yes I think that's the problem

Comment: You should explain that in the question, and show it in the code. That's the most important part of your problem.

Comment: In that case you can pass `b` as a parameter (without parenthesis) and execute it within the asynchronous code complete handler (assuming you have one).  See the answer from @Martial for an example.

Comment: The other 2 answers beside mine show how to do that. You could also use promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass `b` to `a` as a callback and then call it inside of `a`.

```js
function a(cb) {
  $('.title').text('3');
  cb()
}

function b() {
  $('.title').eq(0).text('5');
}

$('button').on('click', function() {
  a(b);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='title'>title</div>
<div class='title'>title</div>
<div class='title'>title</div>
<div class='title'>title</div>

<button>CLICK</button>
```

You could also return a promise from `a` and `then` call a `b` function after `a` is resolved. This way if you have asynchronous call in `a`, `b` will wait until that `a` resolved and you can also use what is returned from `a`.

```js
function a() {
  $('.title').text('3')
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(5), 1000)
  })
}

function b(n) {
  $('.title').eq(0).text(n);
}

$('button').on('click', function() {
  a().then(b)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='title'>title</div>
<div class='title'>title</div>
<div class='title'>title</div>
<div class='title'>title</div>

<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: Is it possible without `setTimeout`, pls

Comment: @qadenza Sure that is just to simulate async call

Answer (score 1):

If you add parenthesis after a function name, the function is executed immediately.
With `a(b())`, the result of `b()` is passing to `a()`. Since you want to pass the function itself, you juste have to pass the function name.

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
  a(b);
});
```

Then you have to call the function inside `a()`

```
function a(callback) {
  $('.title').text('3');
  callback();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$("#but").click(function(){
$('.title').text('3');
$('.title').eq(0).text('5');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'>title</div>
<div class='title'>title</div>
<div class='title'>title</div>
<div class='title'>title</div>
<button id="but">CLICK</button>
```